# Visual Studio Exception Settings Search shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

What is the keyboard shortcut to get into 'Search' ?

[image]

Comment: It seems that there is none. Even with TAB you will not get to the search field. Nice find

Comment: Opened uservoice meanwhile https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/34243507-reach-search-box-using-keyboard-in-exceptions-wind